# How to layout a grid of 2 by 3 div (containing image and text) in CSS3 and HTML5

Tags: css, html, layout

I have 6 divs inside of an article content box.

the 6 divs contain would be split up 2 divs per line

i want these divs to fit the horizontal space tightly

this means that the first div should start at the far left and the second should be tight on the far right.

what is the best way of laying out a grid layout like this

[image]

Comment: Do you want to generate it dynamic or static way? I mean if your content come from a database it must be dynamic generated. Think about!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<article class="container" style="overflow:hidden">
    <div style="width:50%; float:left;">1st Div</div> <!-- alternate floating if your width is less than 50%. if it's 50% you can leave all float left -->
    <div style="width:50%; float:right;">2nd Div</div>
    <div style="width:50%; float:left;">3rd Div</div>
    <div style="width:50%; float:right;">4th Div</div>
    <div style="width:50%; float:left;">5th Div</div>
    <div style="width:50%; float:right;">6th Div</div> 
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="container clearfix">
    <li>1st Div</li>
    <li>2nd Div</li>
    <li>3rd Div</li>
    <li>4th Div</li>
    <li>5th Div</li>
    <li>6th Div</li> 
</ul>
```

and its style for this

```
.container > li
{
width:50%;
float:left;
}
.container > li:nth-child(odd)
{
float:right;

}
.clearfix:after
{
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix
{
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, what exactly is clearfix by the way, i've seen the phrase thrown around

Comment: The problem happens when a floated element is within a container box, that element does not automatically force the container’s height adjust to the floated element. When an element is floated, its parent no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow.